# Error in my Calculator app I made in React as final project for freeCodeCamp course and can't figure out how to fix it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created calculator app as final project for freeCodeCamp course. As far as I can see, it does fulfil all criteria, but it doesn't pass the test. Test actually seems to show following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode. (http: //127.0.0.1:3000/:1)
Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode. (http: //127.0.0.1:3000/:1)
at r.onerror (https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/vl/bundle.js:575:14032)
at Object. invokeGuardedCallbackDev (static/is/bundle.js: 12074:20)
at invokeGuardedCallback (static/is/bundle. js:12136:35)
at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (static/is/bundle. is: 12151:29)
at executeDispatch (static/js/bundle.js: 16980:7)
at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder(static/js/bundle.js:17012:11)
at processDispatchQueue (static/js/bundle. js:17025:9)
at dispatchEventsForPlugins (static/is/bundle. js:17036:7)
at http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/is/bundle.is:17228:16
at batchedUpdates$1 (static/js/bundle.js: 33863:16)
```

I would appreciate any help or pointers to find where is the error or how to fix it. I am total newbie and want to learn but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

If you would like to download the git and try it, you can simply run already set up server with

```
npm start
```

link to my project on GitHub is:
https://github.com/JiriAU/calculator_react_v1

Answer (score 0):

Found bug that was adding “0” in front of some numbers.
Adding check for that zero and removing it if found solved the problem